# How to pass a numpy scalar to a function nicely in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array `a` and want to pass its elements to a function `func` in a loop:

```
a = np.array([0, 0, 1], dtype='bool')

def func(x):
    if x is True:
        # do something
    else:
        # do something else

for i in np.arange(3):
    res = func(a[i])
```

I expect `a[i]` to be `<class 'bool'>`, but in fact it is `<class 'numpy.bool_'>` and I have to use `a[i].item()` every time to convert it to a python scalar, which is prone to error.

```
for i in np.arange(3):
    res = func(a[i].item())
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: `for x in a.tolist(): res = func(x)` might work. Iterating on a list is faster than iterating on an array.  But are you sure your `func` is bothered by getting a `bool_` object instead of a plain python `bool`?

Comment: If your function is properly duck-typed, this shouldn't been an issue.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the hint. You are right. I have found that if I change the if condition `if x is True:` to `if x:`, then the type is not a problem anymore, but I am still wondering what are the differences between these two if conditions.

Comment: `is` tests for object identity.  `if x:` tests for value, 'truthiness'.  `1`, 'foobar', `[123]` are 'true' without being identical to the unique `True` boolean object.